# D3 svg text position right

Tags: d3.js

I am wondering if there is a way to get svg text of an element to align to the right.  It is currently working, positioned left and wonder if I am missing something simple.

```
svg.append("text")
.attr("class", "role-title") 
.text(function (d) {return d.role;})
.call(wrapText, 190)
.attr('transform', function (d) {
if (d.place === 1) {
return 'translate(75,-40)'; ... // parameter for right align


<text class="role-title" transform="translate(-240, 50)">
  <tspan x="0" dy="0em">Computer and Information</tspan>
  <tspan x="0" dx="0" dy="1.1em">Research Scientist</tspan>
</text>
```

Comment: attribute `text-anchor` set to `end` (??)